# USA average salary, historical data 1930-now

Tags: historical-data, market-data

Is there a historical data for **average salary** in USA, maybe **not very precise**, starting ideally from year 1930?

Any type of salary, before or after tax, and any average - mean, median would be ok.

P.S.

I found data going back to 1970, but need longer history. It should be the average of the real salaries, not things like GDP-per-capita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two sources that I can think of are:

**[US Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/data/)**

As the [BLS is over 135 years old](https://www.bls.gov/bls/history/home.htm) they should have the data.

Based on [this Monthly Labor Review article covering 100 years of data](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2016/article/current-employment-statistics-survey-100-years-of-employment-hours-and-earnings.htm) specifically the footnotes at the bottom mentioning both a document published in 1919 and that "Labor productivity annual data is only available back to 1948. See https://www.bls.gov/lpc/ for more information."

Hopefully your understanding of jargon and appropriate categories is better than mine using their online tool.

and the **[US Internal Revenue Service](https://www.irs.gov/statistics)**

digitized all of their related publications in [Statistics of Income Report Archive](https://www.irs.gov/statistics/soi-tax-stats-archive) which are in PDF format. Unfortunately a quick check of the older PDFs mainly discuss on the taxpayers who paid which isn't necessarily the wage info you are looking for.